# Cosa significa "vacanza" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Di scecchi in groppa, jiumente e mulaccioni, cavalcioni financo a servitori, servi costanti e fidi del barone, dall'aspre pietre, dirupi del Calanna, franti e malati, io nel corpo per troppo accasciamento, il mio criato in testa per **vacanza**, dal romitorio di 
>   cattivitate di quell'insano frate liconario, calammo di leggieri sul paese.

Per aggiungere un po' di contesto, la vicenda narrata accade poco dopo i fatti di Alcàra Li Fusi, durante i quali i personaggi a cui allude il brano si erano rifugiati nel romitorio di Santo Nicolò, dove c'era un eremita pazzo. Riguardante a questo "criato", una frase precedente afferma:

> il mio servo Sasà s'era ridotto a schiavo e succubo del frate, e l'adorava e vaneggiando, il babbalèo, lasciavasi legnare, vestire di cilicio, cosparger la testa di terra e d'escrementi

Ho cercato il termine "vacanza" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capirne il senso  nel passaggio sopra citato, che ha un linguaggio volutamente ottocentesco perché è parte di una lunga lettera che scrive il barone di Mandralisca. Qualcuno di voi mi sa spiegare cosa significa?

Per quanto riguarda il vocabolo "liconario", qualche giorno fa avevo trovato cosa vuol dire in questo [dizionario etimologico di meridionalismi dell'Università di Nizza](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/legnare.htm) ma, purtroppo, sembra che non funzioni più. In siciliano sarebbe "lupunariu" e significa "licantropo". Infatti si tratta di una mistura probabilmente inventata dall'autore dei vocaboli "licantropo" e "lupunariu" (italianizzato).

Comment: Io penso che il significato di vacanza sia quello di mancanza. Infatti chi parla dice di essere franto e malato nel corpo per troppo accasciamento (o debolezza), e il mio criato (è malato) in testa per vacanza, cioè mancanza delle sue doti intellettuali.

Comment: @abarisone: Quindi sarebbe il fatto di "vacare" o "esser vuoto". Cioè, il criato era malato perché in certo modo aveva la mente vuota. Veramente ha senso.

Comment: Solitamente definire una persona "una testa vuota" vuol dire che non ha grandi doti intellettuali e, per estensione, si puó definire così anche una persona malata.

Comment: @abarisone: Penso che fosse malato nel senso che si era lasciato dominare dalla pazzia dell'eremita tale com'è descrito nella frase che ho citato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Io penso che il significato di ***vacanza*** nel contesto da te citato sia quello di ***mancanza***.

Il termine deriva da [vacare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vacare/):

> **vacare** v. intr. [dal lat. *vacare* «essere privo di; essere vacante;
>   avere tempo libero per ...», e quindi «dedicarsi a»]

Infatti chi parla dice di essere franto e malato nel corpo per troppo accasciamento (o debolezza), e il mio criato (è malato) in testa per vacanza, cioè mancanza delle sue doti intellettuali.